# Visualization of MP3 - PHP

Tags: php, api, mp3

I'm trying to build an mp3 player for my site using JavaScript (and any plugins/frameworks(jQuery)/libraries that are relevant) & html5. So I built the player (more accurately, I implemented jPlayer), and now I want to make a visualizer.

*Ok maybe it's not a visualizer (all the names for ways to visualize sound always confused me), I guess what I want is something like this (Update: I just found out this is called a [waveform](https://www.google.com/search?q=waveform&gws_rd=ssl)):*

[image: wavelenghth]
<sub>(source: [anthonymattox.com](http://www.anthonymattox.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/processing_audio_waveform_spectrum_2.jpg))</sub>

*Or just something that graphs the amplitude (loudness) of an MP3.*

I've been told I [can't do that with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638552/get-relative-loudness-of-song-javascript/6638786#6638786).

**So does anyone know how to do it with php?**

More accurately, does anyone know how to graph the loudness/amplitude of an MP3 using PHP? I know that once I get the loudness I can make a graph using GD or the Google graphs image API.

Any API's, ideas, frameworks will all be much appreciated!

Comment: Fantastic question. Wish I had the answer, but looking forward to seeing what people come up with...

Comment: As far as I know, there are no PHP modules for decoding MP3 files. If you're willing to make an MP3 parser yourself, however, nothing keeps you from reading binary files in JavaScript.

Comment: @zneak there has to be an Apache tool I can call with shell exec to at least print some (useful) data to a text file...

Comment: I can guarantee this is possible to do in php itself, just depends on how much coding you want to do by yourself I guess lol

Comment: OK! SO I found a way to turn wav's to waveforms: http://phpclasses.cfappsinc.ca/browse/file/1582.html, now to tackle mp3's

Comment: As a matter of fact now you can do it with mp3 , actually you could do that way back then aswell. Right now you can either use Webkits WebAudio and or Mozillas MozAudio Api for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adverse to using PHP to call out to command line tools on the system?  If not, then I would suggest using `mpg123` to convert the mp3 temporarily to .wav, and then a utility called [`wav2png.py`](http://www.freesound.org/blog/?p=10) to generate the waveform as a .png image.

This is going to be slow, memory-hungry, and disk-hungry, since it requires conversion to .wav first.

```
exec("mpg123 -w outfile.wav infile.mp3");

// Not sure of the syntax for wav2png...
exec("wav2png.py outfile.wav");
```

*Disclaimer: I have no experience with wave2png.py, and am merely aware of its existence.*

Comment: Nothing against command line tools (although I'd prefer php...), I'm just trying to prevent abusing the CPU and converting mp3 to wav just for the png, well I'm not sure that that is worth it...

Comment: @Tomas: you'd have to anyways. MP3 is compressed lossy data. It's not a direct representation of a waveform, so you have to decompress it to raw PCM (pulse-code modulation, aka a waveform) be to able to get graphable data.